# Ubuntu 20.04, Firewalld: Am able to SSH from outside of Source Address

Tags: linux, firewall, firewalld

So I'm going through the setting up local firewalls on linux servers for work. Today I created two new zones: zoneA and zoneB. Zonea has snmp and ssh services added, also has 4 subnets and 1 ip address added as source address. Zoneb has only tcp/443 added with a source address of: target:ACCEPT

Went to test and I get prompted for a password when I attempt to SSH from a host outside of those specified subnets.

Systemctl shows a status if running. Both zones show (active) when I do a --list-all

What did I do wrong here?

Comment: Ssh asking for a password seems normal. What do you want to obtain (ssh-key authentication ?).

Comment: What is the default zone (sudo firewall-cmd --get-default-zone) ?

Comment: @FrédéricLoyer I am new to firewalld and iptables but according to the bits I've read I expected the packets to be dropped if attempting to access the system from a host that's outside the specified source addresses.

Comment: @golder3 I set the default zone to ZoneA.  It's my understanding the other built-in zones are not in play unless made active in some way. I was worried that those would need to be removed.

Comment: maybe I'm not correct in thinking that the target can be default/accept and able to scope access via source address values?  Do I need to set a reject or drop on the target level?

Comment: @Skeer Yes, what is your current target ?

Comment: @golder3 So the idea is to just limit the possible attack surface. Granted this is for internal hosts.. but it's what the boss wants. So like, a default block, but then a zone for say HTTPS (because it's a license server), then another zone for the allowed SSH in, and a third zone for mgmt applications (Ansible, LogicMonitor, etc).  I don't know if that is ideal or not but logically it sounds good in my head.